# Fourier series solution of differential equation (Dirac Delta)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, dirac-delta

I have been given the following:

$$y''(x)+\omega^2y(x)=s(x),$$

$$s(x)= \delta(x)-\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})$$   for $-\frac{1}{4}<x<\frac{3}{4}$. 
 (Periodically repeating for x outside this interval.)

Question:
Find the Fourier series solution y(x) of the above differential equation.
I am completely lost, as I am unsure of how to expand s(x) into a Fourier series.
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the definition of the Fourier series, and what happens when you apply $s$ to it? You'll get better answers if you show everything you've tried so far!

Answer (score 1):

So, write 
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}y_{n}e^{2\pi{inx}}$$
Plug into the equation
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big(\omega^{2}-(2\pi{n})^{2}\big)y_{n}e^{2\pi{inx}}=\delta(x)-\delta(x-1/2)$$
Multiply by $e^{-2\pi{imx}}$ and integrate over $[-1/4, 3/4]$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big(\omega^{2}-(2\pi{n})^{2}\big)y_{n}\int_{-1/4}^{3/4}e^{2\pi{i(n-m)x}}dx=1-e^{-\pi{i}m}$$
$$\int_{-1/4}^{3/4}e^{2\pi{i(n-m)x}}dx=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}{i(n-m)}}\int_{0}^{1}e^{2\pi{i(n-m)z}}dz=\delta_{mn}$$
Thus,
$$\big(\omega^{2}-(2\pi{m})^{2}\big)y_{m}=1-e^{-\pi{i}m}$$
hence
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{e^{2\pi{inx}}-e^{2\pi{in(x-1/2)}}}{\omega^{2}-(2\pi{n})^{2}}$$

Comment: Where did you get the equation from (∑n∈Z(ω2−(2πn)2)yne2πinx=δ(x)−δ(x−1/2))

Comment: I pluged $y(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}y_{n}e^{2\pi{inx}}$ into $y''+\omega^{2}y=\delta(x)-\delta(x-1/2)$

Comment: may be a stupid question, but what is $y_n$?

Comment: Fourier coefficient of $y(x)$. It was determined to be $y_{n}=\frac{1-e^{-i\pi{n}}}{\omega^{2}-(2\pi{n})^{2}}$

Comment: have you assumed a period of 2pi, because surely this is periodic about 1

Comment: I've done the expansion in terms of the complete set of functions on $[-1/4, 3/4]$ (or $[0, 1]$ if you wish), because that is what your problem requires.

Comment: Looks like my style of writing is very poor)) Need to add more comments in future...

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but I am trying to understand what you have done and am still unsure of a few things. From what I understand, you are 'guessing' a solution y(x). It is after this point I get lost. Why do you multiply by $e^{-2piimx}$, what is m, then what is delta_mn. Also when finding the fourier coefficents, how do you do that?

Comment: I'm not guessing. You are searching for a solution on $[-1/4, 3/4]$. The set of functions $\{e^{2\pi{i}nx}\}_{n}$ forms an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^{2}([-1/4, 3/4])$. The inner (scalar) product is given by $<m|n>=\int_{-1/4}^{3/4}e^{-2\pi{i}mx}e^{2\pi{i}nx}dx=\delta_{mn}$. Where $\delta_{mn}$ is a Kronecker symbol, it is equal to $0$ $m\neq{n}$ and it is equal to $1$ only when $m=n$, i.e. it reflects the orthonormality of our basis. So I do the expansion because by completeness I can expand any function $y(x)\in\mathcal{L}^{2}([-1/4, 3/4])$ in the basis.

Comment: I multiply the equation by an orthogonal function $e^{-2\pi{i}mx}$ and integrate. The integration gives $\delta_{mn}$ on the left, so the only non-zero term in the sum is $n=m$, which is $(\omega^{2}-(2\pi{m})^{2})y_{m}$. On the right, integration gives me $1-e^{-\pi{i}mx}$, by definition of the delta function. Thus $(\omega^{2}-(2\pi{m})^{2})y_{m}=1-e^{-\pi{i}mx}$, so the $m^{th}$ expansion coefficient is $y_{m}=\frac{1-e^{-\pi{i}mx}}{\omega^{2}-(2\pi{m})^{2}}$. So, the solution is $y(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1-e^{-\pi{i}nx}}{\omega^{2}-(2\pi{n})^{2}}e^{2\pi{i}nx}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The Fourier series for a function $f(x)$ on the interval $[-L, L]$ is defined as $$f(x) \sim\frac {a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} + b_n \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L}}$$
where $$a_n = \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L}$$ and $$b_n = \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L}$$
And if $f(x)$ is continuous on $(-L, L)$ then this is an equality.