# Dirac Delta Intuition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, dirac-delta

I am considering the following forcing function (part of a differential equation)
$$s(x)=\delta(x)-\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})$$
I was just wondering if someone could provide me with some intuition of what this 'function' looks like. I am thinking that it is zero everywhere except at $x=0,x=\frac{1}{2}$, where it is infinite.

I need to expand this as a Fourier series in order to solve the differential equation, and I think this intuition may help me.

The differential equation is:
$$y''(x)+\omega^2=s(x)$$ If you're interested.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: is $\omega $ a costant? if yes then you could try to integrate both terms twice in order to solve the equation.

Comment: it is a constant, yes. How would I integrate though, as the dirac delta is infinite at two points?

Comment: If $\int dx\,f(x)\delta(x)= f(0)$ then by linearity of the integrals you will get the sum of your integrand at those points where the argument of each $\delta$ is $0$.  Of course here is crucial observation is that the Fourier transform of the constant function is a $\delta$ and conversely the Fourier transform of a $\delta$ is the constant function.

Comment: Do you mean Fourier transform? You can't have a Fourier series of infinite domain

Comment: The integral of the dirac is just the heavyside function.

Comment: Ok, so using the fourier series to model some periodic function of period 2l: we have:$\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_n^\inf a_n cos(\frac{n\pi x}{l})+\sum_n^\inf b_n sin(\frac{n\pi x}{l})$. Where $a_0=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}s(x).dx$, $a_n=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}s(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{l})dx$, $b_n=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}s(x)sin(\frac{n\pi x}{l}).dx$. How would I go about finding the coefficients. I think what is confusing me is the fact that there is two parts to the dirac function.

Comment: The periodic extension of the Delta function is the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb), which has the Fourier series
$$ F(\xi) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{in\pi \xi}{L}} $$

Comment: Are you sure that your equation is completely reproduced? It would make more sense as oscillator $$y''(x)+ω^2y(x)=s(x).$$

Comment: @LutzL: You seem to have a point: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2543789/11127) was asked by OP 21 hours earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok we have: $y''(x)+\omega^2=\delta(x)-\delta(x- 1/2).$ The integral of $\delta(x)$ is $H(x)$ which is the heavyside function: $H(x)=1, \forall x\ge 0$ and $H(x)=0 \; \forall x<0$. Now we integrate twice and we get:
$$y(x)=-\omega^2 \frac{x^2}{2}+c_2+c_1x+xH(x)-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)H(x-\frac{1}{2}).$$ The integrate of $H(x)$ should be easy to compute, just draw $H(x)$ if you are not getting it.

Comment: This makes sense, but I have been told I have to use a Fourier series to solve it

Comment: If you want to solve a differential equation of the second order you will have a function that depends on two conditions. Then if you have for example $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ which could be position and speed at time zero, you just use them to find $c_1$ and $c_2$. Those are simply the constants of the integrations.

Comment: Surely you cannot integrate $\delta (x)$ unless you multiply it by some function, say i were computing the fourier series of s(x). If i were to compute the integrals: $$a_0=2\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \delta (x) \delta (x-\frac{1}{2}) .dx$$. $$a_n=2\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \delta (x) \delta (x-\frac{1}{2}) cos(n \pi x) .dx$$ $$b_n=2\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \delta (x) \delta (x-\frac{1}{2}) sin(n \pi x) .dx$$  surely I could not compute $a_0$ as there is no function that the dirac function is being multiplied by?

Comment: mmm the fact is that if you want to resolve it with fourier's series you must know more about $y(x)$, it should be periodic and you should know its period.

Comment: I was given that:$$s(x)=\delta(x)-\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})$$ for$$ -\frac{1}{4}<x<\frac{3}{4}$$ periodically repeating for x outside that interval

Comment: Then you can do the calculation of the coefficients for both $\delta(x)$ and $\delta(x-1/2)$, (and you have the equality in the sense of distributions) but in order to expand $y(x)$ you need it to be periodic as $s(x)$ is. Otherwise you can't use the common base of $L^2\left( \left( -\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right) \right)$.

Comment: If you assume that you can expand both $y(x),s(x)$. Pay attention at the factors in the integrals, they are $cos(\frac{2\pi n x}{I}),sin(\frac{2\pi n x}{I})$ where $I$ is the length of the interval and the constant term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Beginnings look here for reference.